# Show element inside a DIV with overflow-y on top of all others

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index

I have the following tooltip:

```css
#left_div {
  max-height:170px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
a.tditems_tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  max-width:400px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  line-height:16px;
  padding:0;
  background:url('/layouts/background.gif');
  border: 1px solid #CFB57C;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #AAAAAA;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  max-width:800px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover.tditems_tooltip span {
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="400" height="300">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <div id="left_div">
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        <a class="tditems_tooltip">
          <font color="red">TRIGGER</font>
          <span>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="300">
              <tr bgcolor="green">
                  <td>CONTENT OF TOOLTIP</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </span>
        </a>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">INSIGNIFICANT CONTENT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And so far It is working almost perfectly to what I intend to... Except for one thing: The tooltip (`span`) doesn't show on the top of all other elements of the page, instead shows behind it. Checkout the snippet above.

> **NOTE:** When I remove from the **CSS** the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` from the `td` it shows the way intended, but I still need to specify a `max-height` to that `td`...

Any ideas?

Comment: Removing overflow from the td is what you need to do, but what do you mean you still need to specify a max-height? the max-height and height you have now are being ignored because the value for them is invalid, so no need for either of them.

Comment: @MichaelCoker sorry about that, could you run the snippet now?

Comment: I see it changed, but the behavior still seems the same. Removing `overflow` from the element fixes it. The behavior of `max-height` seems the same whether you have `overflow` defined or not. What's wrong with just removing `overflow`?

Comment: I can't remove it because I need the scrolling bars to show, as it does in the snippet execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `position: fixed;` to a child element will remove it from the flow of that element's parents in the DOM, so the child element will ignore any `overflow` properties of parent elements.

Assigning fixed positioning to the table that contains the tooltip seems to force that element outside of the overflow properties of it's parents, but then positioned itself differently within the absolutely positioned span element, so I applied `transform: translateY(-100%);` to make it work with your example. You may need to re-work the layout of those elements to get it to work as you'd it to. (btw, the styles I added are under `a.tditems_tooltip span > table`)

```css
#left_div {
  max-height:170px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
a.tditems_tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  max-width:400px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  line-height:16px;
  padding:0;
  background:url('/layouts/background.gif');
  border: 1px solid #CFB57C;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #AAAAAA;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  max-width:800px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover.tditems_tooltip span {
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a.tditems_tooltip span > table {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="400" height="300">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <div id="left_div">
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        <a class="tditems_tooltip">
          <font color="red">TRIGGER</font>
          <span>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="300">
              <tr bgcolor="green">
                  <td>CONTENT OF TOOLTIP</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </span>
        </a>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">INSIGNIFICANT CONTENT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```